# How to define exceptions for the Third occurence of a DIV?

Tags: css, css-selectors

**CSS**

```
#columns{
   width:100px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html><body>
  <div id=columns>..1..</div>
  <div id=columns>..2..</div>
  <div id=columns>..3..</div>
  <div id=columns>..4..</div>
  <div id=columns>..5..</div>
  <div id=columns>..6..</div>  
</body></html>
```

Now, imagine that I want to define in CSS3, a specific rule to make an exception for the Third and Sixth div, which I want to make 50px. is there another way ( besode making a new div name, obviously, as I want to make things elegant and have all of them use the exact same div ID.

Any suggestions to how to solve this are very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but you can't have more than one element with the same ID. You can achieve real elegance by using classes, because then your document will validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For browsers which support the CSS3 [`nth-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) pseudo-class:

```
    <style type="text/css">
      div > div { 
        width: 100px; 
      }
      div:nth-child(3), div:nth-child(6) {
        width: 50px;
      }
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
    <div>
      <div>..1..</div>
      <div>..2..</div>
      <div>..3..</div>
      <div>..4..</div>
      <div>..5..</div>
      <div>..6..</div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[:nth-child()](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html)

http://jsfiddle.net/tRbWP/

Answer (score 1):

Use the nth-child pseudo class, with 0n so it picks a child without grouping.

```
div:nth-child(3), div:nth-child(6) { width: 50px; }
```